# Полиморфизм Java

Tags: java, полиморфизм, переопределение

Когда я переопределяю метод из базового класса с помощью `@Override` - это статическое связывание, а когда без - динамическое. Правильно ли я понимаю?

Comment: Если вопрос решил вашу проблему, то примите его, нажав рядом с ним галочку.

Answer (score 9):

Нет, `@Override` лишь аннотация, которая указывает на переопределение метода родительского класса. Если все корректно, метод будет переопределен независимо от ее присутствия или отсутствия. Использование аннотации позволяет сделать код более читаемым и защититься от ошибки, если такой метод в родительском классе или интерфейсе не найден.

Answer (score 5):

> Аннотацию `@Override` следует обязательно указывать.

Если ее не указать, и в сигнатуре переопределяемого метода допустить ошибку, то при компиляции *создастся новый метод*, а нужный не будет переопределен. Данную ошибку достаточно трудно отловить.

На пример у вас есть метод: (требует переопределения)

```
setLocalePositionOfCircle();
```

А вы написали: (без `@Override`)

```
setLocalePositionofCircle() {} // вместо of -> Of
```

То в итоге получится два метода:

```
setLocalePositionOfCircle(); // который нужно было переопределить
setLocalePositionofCircle() {} // который не был переопределен, из за допущенной ошибки
```

Answer (score 0):

Про аннотацию @Override правильно написали выше. А я дополню, что переопределение как таковое (не важно с аннотирование @Override или без) - это пример динамического (позднего) связывания. А пример статического (раннего) связывания - это перегрузка методов.

Answer (score 0):

> @Override - это статическое связывание, а когда без - динамическое. Правильно ли я понимаю?

Нет, неверно. Это в любом варианте только динамическое связывание (*override*). Статическое связывание (перегрузка - по другому *overloading*) работает только со статическими методами.

> Аннотацию @Override следует обязательно указывать.

Нет, неверно. Аннотация `@Override` используется только для удобства программиста, чтобы ненароком не допустить ошибку в сигнатуре метода.